# Unable to connect to internet using Android wifi tethering (hotspot) in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dns, tethering

I'm unable to connect to Internet when using Android WiFi hot-spot (I'm able to connect to hot-spot, but not able to access Internet).

When I use a WiFi router Internet works fine. In chrome I get `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG` error.

I tried removing `/etc/resolv.conf`, updating DNS server addresses to `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` (Google's public dns). But no luck with these.

Did anyone face similar issue? If so, Is there a solution for this problem?

System details:
Ubuntu 14.04 on HP pavilion laptop.
Ralink wireless driver.

Comment: you should not remove .conf files, you need them. if anything, change the configuration but do not remove the file

Comment: Why cant you check with other browser like I.E & Firefox to connect internet.It Seemed to be browser issue.

Comment: Can you verify other devices have proper access through the Android hotspot?

Comment: @vembutech: I.E.???

Comment: @mchid Removing /etc/resolv.conf was one of the suggested solution for dns problems. Removing it will make /etc/resolvconf scripts fix the dns problems, In not sure how this works tough.

Comment: @Donald Brown. Yes, android wifi hotspot works in other android and windows devices. It works in ubuntu 12.04 too!!!

Comment: It is most likely completely irrelevant, but what Android device are you using for hotspot?

Comment: I'm using Moto G.

Comment: have you tried to add the hotspot using network manager?

Comment: @mchid I'm connected to an android wifi hotspot. But not able to connect to internet.

Comment: if you want to set your dns to 8.8.8.8 in network manager, First click on connection information, note your ip, subnet mask, and the default route. Then you actually have to change the ipv4 settings "method" from "automatic" (or "automatic with addresses") to "manual". Click on "Add" type in the IP, use the tab button, type subnet mask, use tab, type default route. Click on ipv6 tab and set to ignore and click save. Click on the network to reconnect for changes to take effect.

Comment: This is because it is a DNS issue. I see that if I use IP addresses from my Xperia, I am able to connect using the Hotspot. Finally found that by using OpenDNS , I was able to connect successfully. Here are the instructions:
https://support.opendns.com/entries/42848890-Android-Configuration-instructions-for-OpenDNS

Comment: Are you tethering using a 4G mobile handheld device? Try downgrade your data connection from ( 4G,3G,2G or 4G only )to 3G only. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Open Chrome , go to settings and uncheck

```
predict network actions to improve page load performance
```

option. restart chrome. that will fix `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG` issue.

If issue still persists , let me know.

Comment: I've tried all these and chrome's net-internals too. No luck with that.